# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation - PDO "GRANT" prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am trying to create a prepared statement using PDO that will allow me to create mysql users using data collected from a form.
When i run the command though, i get the error:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''select' ON 'testjoke.authors' TO 'corey'@'localhost'' at line 1

I am currently just using data from some variables i created for testing, instead of data from the form.
The code looks like this:

```
$grantQuery = $db->prepare("GRANT ? ON ? TO ?@'localhost';");

    $select = 'select';
    $testjoke = 'testjoke.authors';
    $pdoemail = 'corey';

    $grantQuery ->execute(array(
                                $select,
                                $testjoke,
                    $pdoemail
                ));
```

I have enabled Mysql general logging, and the query never even shows up on it (never executed).

I have been trying to find a fix for this for a couple of days now, but i am having no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Corey

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - frequently asked questions about PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990857/reference-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdo). See this answer in particular ~ [Can I use a PDO prepared statement to bind an identifier (a table or field name) or a syntax keyword?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990857/reference-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdo#15991422)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as you cannot write `SELECT ? FROM ?`, neither can you divide `GRANT` into a prepared query.

Prepared query values can only be values. For safety reasons among many others, you cannot pass in keywords. The only parameter that *might* work in your case is the username, as that is a string.

PDO is trying to run:

```
GRANT 'select' ON 'testjoke.authors' TO 'cory':'localhost';
```

You can see why this won't work, I hope.

Comment: Hi, Ok thanks, i wasnt aware that you couldnt pass keywords into PDO (i am quite new to mysql/php). Thanks again, Cheers, Corey

Comment: Things like this are part of the reason why I was so adamant about sticking with the outdated `mysql_` functions, but ultimately you shouldn't *need* variable tables/columns and suchlike.